# Error al enviar multilpes archivos por sockets UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 5

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket

Tego un programa sencillo cliente-servidor, en el cual trato de enviar el contenido de mi carpeta **Documentos** que contiene 2 archivos ["img1.jpg","img2.jpg"].

**Funcionamiento:**

El servidor espera a que se conecte un cliente y recibe los mensajes del mismo, pero si el mensaje es el texto: **archivos** entonces se inicia la función `crearExp()` que recibe el nombre de la nueva carpeta a crear y la cantidad de archivos que va ha recibir.

Con esos datos inicio un ciclo `for` que tiene que repetirse segun la cantidad de archivos que el usuario le indico al servidor.

***Ciclo for:***

Este ciclo tiene como funcion recibir los datos de cada uno de los archivos que le mandde le cliente y posteriormente guardardos en la ruta indicada.

**Problema:**

El servidor recibe correctamente una parte pequeña de los datos, pero despues lanza un error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\servidor_recv_archivo.py", line 53, in <module>
    if msgp.decode() == "archivos":
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 5: invalid
start byte
```

**Servidor.py**

```
import socket
import os

def bytes_a_entero(b):
    resultado = 0
    for i in range(4):
        resultado += b[i]<<(i*8)
    return resultado

def crearExp(cliente):
    while True:
        NombreCarpeta = cliente.recv(1024).decode()
        NoArchivos = cliente.recv(1024).decode()

        print(NombreCarpeta,NoArchivos)
        if not os.path.exists(NombreCarpeta):
            os.mkdir(NombreCarpeta)

        for elemento in range(int(NoArchivos)):
            size = cliente.recv(4)
            size = bytes_a_entero(size)
            size_actual = 0
            buffer = b""
            while size_actual < size:
                data = cliente.recv(1024)
                if not data:
                    break
                if len(data) + size_actual > size:
                    data = data[:size-size_actual]
                buffer += data
                size_actual += len(data)
            with open(str(elemento),"wb") as f:
                f.write(buffer)
        break

ip = "192.168.8.8"
puerto = 5555
data = (ip,puerto)
conexiones = 2

servidor = socket.socket()
servidor.bind(data)
servidor.listen(conexiones)

cliente,direccion = servidor.accept()

while True:
    try:
        msgp = cliente.recv(1024)

        print(msgp)
        cliente.sendall("Msg recivido".encode())
        if msgp.decode() == "archivos":
            crearExp(cliente)
    except ConnectionResetError:
        print("{} se fue".format(direccion))
        break
```

**Cliente.py**

```
import socket
import os

def convertir_a_bytes(longitud):
    resultado = bytearray()
    resultado.append(longitud&255)
    for i in range(3):
        longitud = longitud>>8
        resultado.append(longitud&255)
    return resultado

def crearCarpetaServ(cliente):
    Ruta = "C:/Users/AngelHp/Desktop/Documentos"
    NombreCarpeta = os.path.basename("C:/Users/AngelHp/Desktop/Documentos")
    NoArchivos = str(len(os.listdir("C:/Users/AngelHp/Desktop/Documentos")))

    cliente.sendall(NombreCarpeta.encode())
    cliente.sendall(NoArchivos.encode())

    for elemento in (os.listdir(Ruta)):
        longitud = os.path.getsize(Ruta+"/"+elemento)
        cliente.send(convertir_a_bytes(longitud))
        with open(Ruta+"/"+elemento,"rb") as infile:
            d = infile.read(1024)
            while d:
                cliente.send(d)
                d = infile.read(1024)

ip = "192.168.8.8"
puerto = 5555

cliente = socket.socket()
cliente.connect((ip,puerto))

while True:
    msg = input("> ")
    if msg != "archivos": #Al oprimir el boton guarar en serv, lanzara la funcion crearExpServ
        cliente.sendall(msg.encode())
        respuesta = cliente.recv(1024).decode()
        print(respuesta)
    elif msg == "archivos":
        print("ok")
        crearCarpetaServ(cliente)
```

Comment: No tengo claro la raíz del problema, pero quizás te ayude saber que el problema es causado porque los bytes que esta recibiendo el servidor no es una cadena de caracteres codificados con utf-8, por lo que deberías revisar la parte en que se codifica en bytes en el cliente y la parte que se decodifica en el servidor estén hablando el mismo idioma.